# Android: Что это за виджет

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такой виджет в Android, когда мы пальцем свайпаем влево/вправо выбирая какой-то элемент. Либо же из каких стандартных виджетов можно подобное собрать, спасибо!

Чтобы посмотреть, нужно с телефона зайти на этот сайт: https://taketape.it/it/nastro-b2c.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл сказать, есть идея это сделать в виде linear layout(horizontal), туда суем recyclerview и сам кружок с надписью будет как .xml

Comment: похож на принцип работы ViewPager

Comment: можно погуглить по запросу pager indicator, [например](https://androidexample365.com/dot-based-android-viewpager-indicator-with-material-design-animations/)